# How can I create an SQL query from a List<string> contained in a Session["id"]?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

I have a session that contains a list of strings that represent Primary Keys in SQL tables.
I'd like to use the Visual Studio drag'n'drop SqlDataSource to specify a custom SELECT Query and link that to a gridview. I'm still learning. The query might look like this: (note: I'm new to SQL)

`SELECT *
    FROM myDatabase
        WHERE itemID = (any of the things in Session["cart"])`

I'd like to produce a gridview populated with all the items (name, description etc.) that have their itemID in that session.

Is this sort of thing possible? And would I need to change the data type of the list from string to int32 or something? Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can do it in codebehind (possibly in designer too, but that may complicate things). Suggestion: Do not use SqlDataSource ;)

Comment: The only bit I understood was: do not use SQLDataSource.

Comment: @user2247353: Response to your comment in Yair Nevet's answer. SO is StackOverflow! It's hard to tell why your SQL is not working without seeing it. If the IDs are numbers the In-clause should look like `IN (1, 2, 3)`. If they are strings it should look like this `IN ('a', 'b', 'c')` with string delimiters.

Comment: Ok I added a connection string to the SqlDataSource1 and now it works. I'm going to study how it works so I'll learn. Thanks for helping me with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like to produce a gridview populated with all the items (name,
>   description etc.) that have their itemID in that session.

You can simply access to your `SqlDataSource` control object in the code-behind and construct your `SELECT` query based on the `Session` IDs data, do it like that:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var itemIDs = string.Join(",", ((IList<string>)Session["id"]).ToArray());
        var sqlQuery = String.Format("SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE itemID IN ({0})", itemsIDs);

        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = sqlQuery;
        GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

**What am I doing:**

1. Projection all IDs from the `Session["Items"]` list object into a string.
2. Pass it to the `SQLDataSource`'s `SelectCommand` programmatically by using the sql `IN` clause so I can query for multiple ids.
3. Pass the `SQLDataSource` to the `GridView1.DataSource`.
4. Bind it all back on the `GridView1`.

Comment: Ok I added a connection string to the SqlDataSource1 and now it works. I'm going to study how it works so I'll learn. Thanks for helping me with it.

Comment: @user2247353 Great! without a Connection-String you can't do any query.. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using sessions, then you really should do the work in the code behind file. You can use a datasource, infact use a datasource, but please read up on execution of sql queries in c# or VB. Then when such a query is executed, that returned table etc is bound to the datasource. Automatically, that table is displayed. Hope this helps. Ask further questions if you need more clarification. Sorry my answer is too over the place, i haven't got time today